# Cannot creat database tabele: syntax error

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create mysql db table as below, but it got a syntax error at line 4.

```
CREATE TABLE findable_drivers (
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
driver_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
current_role VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, #here
lat DOUBLE NOT NULL,
lng DOUBLE NOT NULL,
findable BOOLEAN  DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT findable_drivers_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT findable_drivers_UN UNIQUE KEY (driver_id),
CONSTRAINT findable_drivers_driver_FK FOREIGN KEY (driver_id) REFERENCES driver(id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci ;
```

the error description:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_role VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
> lat DOUBLE NOT NULL,
> lng DOUBLE NOT N...' at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CURRENT_ROLE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-role) is actually a MySQL/MariaDB system function which returns active roles for the current session.  So in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, the database thinks you are trying to call this function.  You should call the `current_role` column something else.  If you must stick with this name, then will have to forever refer to it using backticks:

```sql
CREATE TABLE findable_drivers (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    driver_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    `current_role` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,  -- must use backticks here
    lat DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    lng DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    findable BOOLEAN  DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT findable_drivers_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT findable_drivers_UN UNIQUE KEY (driver_id),
    CONSTRAINT findable_drivers_driver_FK FOREIGN KEY (driver_id) REFERENCES driver(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
  COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct
It would be good if you use different column name than the defined keywords.